# Как получить json c одного компонента и передать в другой

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент Speakers.js в который я вывожу компоненты Filter и List. В компоненте List.js я делаю запрос fetch, получаю json с сервера и вывожу элементы эти на странице. Проблема в том что мне нужно ведь для того чтобы работал фильтр - получить эти же данные и в компонент filter, чтобы в нем я мог например в поле name найти конкретного человека и чтобы у меня вместо 100 учащихся показывался только тот которого я искал. Мне нужно передать эти данные с fetch(List.js) в filter.js или в filter.js мне снова нужно сделать такойже самый запрос как в List.js? Буду признателен за помощь если обьясните как правильно сделать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

speakers.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Filters from './Filters';
    import List from './List';

    const Speakers = () =>  {
        return (
            <div className="speakers">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Filters/>
                    <List/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default Speakers;
```

filter.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Filters extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="filters">
                <div className="alert shadow">
                    <form>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-10">
                                    <label>Name/Surname</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 align-self-center text-center">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Filters;
```

list.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Speakers extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoading: false,
                items: []
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({isLoading: true});
            fetch("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(
                    (result) => {
                        this.setState({
                            items: result,
                            isLoading: false
                        });
                    }
                )
                .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
        }
        render() {
            const {items, isLoading} = this.state;
            if (isLoading) {
                return <p>Loading ...</p>;
            } 

            return (
                <div className="speakers__list">
                    <div className="row">
                        {items.map((item, index) => (
                            <div className="col-md-3" key={index}>
                                <div className="card form-group shadow">
                                    <div className="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{item.first} {item.last}</h5>
                                        <p>{item.email}</p>
                                        <p>{item.address}</p>
                                        <p>{item.balance}</p>
                                        <p>{item.created}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Speakers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае можно передать данные из `List` в родительский компонент, где их получит `Filter`

speakers.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        listObject: {}
    };
}

// Добавляем обработчик получения новых данных
onListUpdate = (listObject) => {
    this.setState({
        listObject: listObject
    });
}

const Speakers = () =>  {
    return (
        <div className="speakers">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Filters
                    listObject={this.state.listObject}
                />
                <List
                    onListUpdate={this.onListUpdate}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

list.js

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    fetch("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: result,
                    isLoading: false
                }, () => {
                    // Передаем записи в родительский объект
                    if(typeof this.props.onListUpdate === 'function') {
                        this.props.onListUpdate(record);
                    }
                });
            }
        )
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}
...
```

filter.js

```
// При получение новых `props` выполняем какие-то действия с данными
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    someActionsWithList(nextProps.listObject);
}
```